# Why I can’t get the int value of css box

Tags: jquery

Here is my css code

```
.b{
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top:0;
     width: 99px;
     height: 99px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     cursor:all-scroll;
  }
```

When I try to get the width of class b use  `$('.b').width()`,I got a strange answer,it is 99.938491, not 100px. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: There are a load of possible reason this could happen. The width could be affected by borders, scaling, padding, margins, and more that I wont list. We'd probably need to see this in action to tell you exactly what's causing it.

Comment: it is working fine here https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/4hxw8e03/1/

Comment: If it's working correctly in the JSFiddle, it's probably some other CSS on your page. I'd suggest using chromes dev tools to have a poke around in the styling for your element, and seeing if you can spot anything that might add width.